# state hooks is not updating state on change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state

I am building a simple blog app and I am trying to update `title` of the blog But it is not updating, it is just showing the current state.

I have tried many times by changing the method of setting state but it is still showing that error.

App.js

```
function BlogDetail() {
    const [blogName, setBlogName] = useState("");


    axios.get("/api/blog_detail/70/").then(res => {

       setBlogName(res.data[0].blog_name)
    })

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value)
    setBlogName({
      ...blogName,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    })
  }

  const saveBlog = (e) => {
   // sending to API
   console.log(blogName)
  }

   return (
       <div>
       <form>

       {blogName}


       <input type="text" name="blogName" value={blogName} onChange={e => handleChange} />

       <button type="submit" onClick={e => saveBlog(e)}>Save</button>


       <form>
       </div>


   )
}
```

And When I update on change instead of updating on submit

```
onChange=(e => setBlogName(e.target.value))
```

Then it is showing

> A component is changing a controlled input to be uncontrolled. This is likely caused by the value changing from a defined to undefined

I have tried many times but it is still not working.

Comment: `blogName` is a **string**, but you're updating it as though it were an object. Just use the value you received directly: `setBlogName(e.target.value)`. (I don't immediately see how that would cause the specific error you've mentioned, but it's incorrect, so...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`input` requires a string as a value, but you are trying to pass an object:

```
setBlogName({
  ...blogName,
  [e.target.name]: e.target.value
})
```

instead pass a string:

```
setBlogName(e.target.value)
```

Also, you need to execute `handleChange` function and pass the `event` param.

```
onChange={e => handleChange(e)}
```

Edit:

Looked at it second time and it should be like this:

```
function BlogDetail() {
    const [blogName, setBlogName] = useState("");

    // without this you override state every time you press a key
    useEffect(() => {
      axios.get("/api/blog_detail/70/").then(res => {

         setBlogName(res.data[0].blog_name)
      })
    }, [])

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    // just use value here
    setBlogName(e.target.value)
  }

  const saveBlog = (e) => {
   // sending to API
   console.log(blogName)
  }

   return (
       <div>
       <form>

       {blogName}

       { /* remember to run the function */ }
       <input type="text" name="blogName" value={blogName} onChange={e => handleChange()} />

       <button type="submit" onClick={e => saveBlog(e)}>Save</button>


       <form>
       </div>


   )
}
```

Comment: I also tried it But it still not changing

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add `e => saveBlog(e)` in question. But it is still not working, I mean updating

Comment: I am setting state when page renders through api and updating after submit

Comment: This `axios.get("/api/blog_detail/70/")` will probably override anything you right into this state. Please wrap it with `useEffect`

Comment: @KonradLinkowski, Wrap what, `get api` ?

Comment: I also believe that `res.data[0].blog_name` is `undefined`

Comment: No, It is showing value from backend

Comment: Does it work after all changes I presented?

Comment: Yes it updating the field but when i click on Save then it is showing blank result on state on page, and also I added `e => handleChange(e)` because it was showing **Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'target'**

Comment: Now it is working, Thanks you very much. But what is the use of `useEffect` on page ?

Comment: You can do this instead: onChange={handleChange}

Comment: @user19652801 if you don't add `useEffect` the request will be sent every time you change the state which means every time you press a button. The response will then override your state so you don't see any changes.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski, Hello again, I am sorry But there is something I want to ask you, When I submit the form then everything is working fine "state is changing", "form is submitting" But when I press on `cancel` form instead of `save` then state is still changing, but I don't want to change state when user choose not to save form, Should i create another functional component to submit the form ?

Comment: @user19652801 I don't see `cancel` anywhere and I don't know how your `cancel` work. Please create another question

Answer (score 1):

Besides the problem that within `handleChange` you need to pass an an string value to `setBlogName` you also need to wrap your axios fetch call in a `useEffect`.

The problem is that everytime you trigger a rerender while calling `setBlogName` you are calling your API point again and set the value back to the fetched value.

You should prevent that by doing the following ->

```
useEffect(() => {
  axios.get("/api/blog_detail/70/").then(res => {
     setBlogName(res.data[0].blog_name)
  }), [])
```

Don't forget to `install { useEffect } from 'react'`.

And well of course update `handleChange` ->

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
    const newBlogPostName = e.target.value
    console.log(newBlogPostName)
    setBlogName(newBlogPostName)
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer, The main problem was of `useEffect` which I was not using.

Answer (score 0):

you have not any action in this method. where is the update state?

```
const saveBlog = (e) => {
   // sending to API
   console.log(blogName)


  }
```

and in this method you change the string to an object

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value)
    setBlogName({
      ...blogName,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

so the problem is that your function updates your state to an object and then you want to display that object(not a string property of that object) in the `DOM`. its wrong because you cant display objects in the `DOM` in react. in this case, you even get an error because you cant use `spread operator` on `strings`. you cant do something like this: `...("test")`

```
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value)
    //the state value will be an object. its wrong. you even get an error 
    because of using spread operator on a string
    setBlogName({
      ...blogName //this is a string at the init time,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    })
  }
```

so whats the solution?
you should update your state to a string or use a string property of the object.
something like this:

```
      const handleChange = (e) => {
        console.log(e.target.value)

        setBlogName("string")
      }

      return (<>{blogName}</>)
```

thats it.